# Codeigniter updating session userdata

Tags: codeigniter, session, updates

I have these session data:

```
"user_id"=>4545,
"user_firstname"=>"Jhon",
"user_email"=>"jhon@myfakeemail.com"
```

if i update for example:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user_email","mynewemail@fakeemail.com");
```

will the enteire session be updated?

will the session get a new session id?

Comment: Why would it? That sort of defeats the purpose of a session no?

Comment: Easiest way to find out, read the official docs or better yet try it out and see.

Comment: @RickCalder nope, i need to update the session on each page load to show always the fresh user's total reputation points

Comment: @crypticツ joking) seems you really like to suggest to read doc )

Comment: @crypticツ +1 for "try it out"

Comment: The point of a session is to persist user data. If updating that usedata created a new session id then the purpose of a session is completely defeated. Changing the email address stored is going to change the email address in that session nothing else

Comment: @RickCalder sure and that is what i need, so if you have the answer post that and i'll accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a session is to persist user data. If updating that usedata created a new session id then the purpose of a session is completely defeated. Changing the email address stored is going to change the email address in that session nothing else